# Why JavaScript function is returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I have no idea why this little thing returns "undefined" when console.log print correct result. Thx in advance.

```
App.Presentation.prototype.getLeaf = function(leafSlug, tree) {
    for (var key in tree.content) {
        if (tree.content[key].type === 'leaf' && tree.content[key].slug === leafSlug) {
            console.log(tree.content[key]) // this works Correct
            return tree.content[key]; // this returns undefined :<
        } else {
            this.getLeaf(leafSlug, tree.content[key]);    
        }
    }
```

};

I'm calling this in console like this:

```
Presentation.getLeaf("chpl", Presentation.tree);
```

And getting this result:

(first result from `console.log`)

```
Object {type: "leaf", alias: "Chpl bla bla bla", slug: "chpl", group: "", order: ""…}
alias: "Chpl bla bla bla"
group: ""
html: "<img src='bg.png' />"
order: ""
parent: "chpl"
slug: "chpl"
type: "leaf"
__proto__: Object
```

(next result from `return`)

```
undefined
```

`Presentation.tree` is a variable containing JSON parsed to object.

Comment: How do you call it and how do you know it returns undefined ?

Comment: I've updated my post, please see it for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `tree.content` has no key where your condition is true, your function never `return`s anything so you get back `undefined`.

And even if some of the recursive calls may `log` something, their result is not used anywhere. You need to return the result of the recursive call from the calling function as well! Change the else-branch to

```
var res = this.getLeaf(leafSlug, tree.content[key]);
if (res)
    return res;
```

Comment: Thanks, however you still didn't post what the function is supposed to do and what result is expected. Is it a simple tree search?

Comment: This is recursive search on tree structure. I have correct mach but I can get it only by `console.log` which get me correct result. `return` give me undefined value.

Comment: Yes. See my answer for the reason and a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the recursive call. There's probably other considerations here, but at some point you'll want to return the result of the recursive call, something like:

```
App.Presentation.prototype.getLeaf = function(leafSlug, tree) {
    for (var key in tree.content) {
        if (tree.content[key].type === 'leaf' && tree.content[key].slug === leafSlug) {
            console.log(tree.content[key]) // this works Correct
            return tree.content[key]; // this returns undefined :<
        } else {
            return this.getLeaf(leafSlug, tree.content[key]);    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Correct recurions search over tree of nested objects should look like this:

```
Presentation.prototype.getLeaf = function(leafSlug, tree) {
    var tempReturn;
    for (var key in tree.content) {
        if (tree.content[key].type === 'leaf' && tree.content[key].slug === leafSlug) {
            return tree.content[key];
        }  else {
            if (tree.content[key] instanceof Object && tree.content[key].hasOwnProperty('content')) {
                tempReturn = this.getLeaf(leafSlug, tree.content[key]);
                if (tempReturn) { return tempReturn }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Instead of calling `this.getLeaf(leafSlug, tree.content[key]);` when nothing was found I had to assign result of this call to variable `tempReturn = this.getLeaf(leafSlug, tree.content[key]);`, check if something was returned `if (tempReturn)` and if yes return that result `{ return tempReturn }`.

I've also added test against end of branch to not to call recursion over `undefined` element:

```
if (tree.content[key] instanceof Object && tree.content[key].hasOwnProperty('content')) {...}
```